# Simple console text editor

Tags: c#, console, text-editor

I have been following along Gary Bernhardt's excellent video series on "Building a Text Editor From Scratch". It's in Ruby but I wanted to do it in C# just to see how much it differs.

Implementation wise it's faithful to what he does. I do have questions whether the code is up to mark in terms of new C# conventions, haven't violated any biggies or gone overboard with LINQ.

The method `SplitLine` was a head scratcher (really showcased the terseness of Ruby) where his line splitting and new carriage code looks like and I couldn't come up with anything like it in C#.

> ```
> lines[row..row] = [line[0...col],line[col..-1]]
> ```

My C# Code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace TextEditor
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            new Editor().Run();
        }
    }

    class Editor
    {
        Buffer _buffer;
        Cursor _cursor;
        Stack<object> _history;

        public Editor()
        {
            var lines = File.ReadAllLines("foo.txt")
                            .Where(x => x != Environment.NewLine);

            _buffer = new Buffer(lines);
            _cursor = new Cursor();
            _history = new Stack<object>();
        }

        public void Run()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                Render();
                HandleInput();
            }
        }

        private void HandleInput()
        {
            var character = Console.ReadKey();


            if ((ConsoleModifiers.Control & character.Modifiers) != 0 && 
                  character.Key == ConsoleKey.Q)
            {
                Environment.Exit(0);
            }

            else if ((ConsoleModifiers.Control & character.Modifiers) != 0 &&
                  character.Key == ConsoleKey.P)
            {
                _cursor = _cursor.Up(_buffer);
            }

            else if ((ConsoleModifiers.Control & character.Modifiers) != 0 &&
                  character.Key == ConsoleKey.N)
            {
                _cursor = _cursor.Down(_buffer);
            }

            else if ((ConsoleModifiers.Control & character.Modifiers) != 0 &&
                  character.Key == ConsoleKey.B)
            {
                _cursor = _cursor.Left(_buffer);
            }

            else if ((ConsoleModifiers.Control & character.Modifiers) != 0 &&
                  character.Key == ConsoleKey.Z)
            {
                _cursor = _cursor.Right(_buffer);
            }

            else if ((ConsoleModifiers.Control & character.Modifiers) != 0 &&
                 character.Key == ConsoleKey.U)
            {
                RestoreSnapshot();
            }

            else if (character.Key == ConsoleKey.Backspace)
            {
                if (_cursor.Col > 0)
                {
                    SaveSnapshot();
                    _buffer = _buffer.Delete(_cursor.Row, _cursor.Col - 1);
                    _cursor = _cursor.Left(_buffer);
                }
            }

            else if(character.Key == ConsoleKey.Enter)
            {
                SaveSnapshot();
                _buffer = _buffer.SplitLine(_cursor.Row, _cursor.Col);
                _cursor = _cursor.Down(_buffer).MoveToCol(0);
            }

            else
            {
                SaveSnapshot();
                _buffer = _buffer.Insert(character.KeyChar.ToString(), _cursor.Row, _cursor.Col);
                _cursor = _cursor.Right(_buffer);
            }


        }

        private void Render()
        {
            ANSI.ClearScreen();
            ANSI.MoveCursor(0, 0);
            _buffer.Render();
            ANSI.MoveCursor(_cursor.Row, _cursor.Col);
        }       

        private void SaveSnapshot()
        {
            _history.Push(_cursor);
            _history.Push(_buffer);
        }

        private void RestoreSnapshot()
        {
            if( _history.Count > 0 )
            {
                _buffer = (Buffer)_history.Pop();
                _cursor = (Cursor)_history.Pop();
            }
        }
    }

    class Buffer
    {
        string[] _lines;

        public Buffer(IEnumerable<string> lines)
        {
            _lines = lines.ToArray();
        }

        public void Render()
        {
            foreach (var line in _lines)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(line);
            }
        }

        public int LineCount()
        {
            return _lines.Count();
        }

        public int LineLength(int row)
        {
            return _lines[row].Length;
        }

        internal Buffer Insert(string character, int row, int col)
        {
            var linesDeepCopy = _lines.Select(x => x).ToArray();
            linesDeepCopy[row] = linesDeepCopy[row].Insert(col, character);
            return new Buffer(linesDeepCopy);
        }

        internal Buffer Delete(int row, int col)
        {
            var linesDeepCopy = _lines.Select(x => x).ToArray();
            linesDeepCopy[row] = linesDeepCopy[row].Remove(col, 1);
            return new Buffer(linesDeepCopy);
        }

        internal Buffer SplitLine(int row, int col)
        {
            var linesDeepCopy = _lines.Select(x => x).ToList();

            var line = linesDeepCopy[row];

            var newLines = new [] { line.Substring(0, col), line.Substring(col, line.Length - line.Substring(0, col).Length) };

            linesDeepCopy[row] = newLines[0];
            linesDeepCopy[row + 1] = newLines[1];



            return new Buffer(linesDeepCopy);
        }
    }

    class Cursor
    {
        public int Row { get; set; }
        public int Col { get; set; }


        public Cursor(int row=0, int col=0)
        {
            Row = row;
            Col = col;
        }

        internal Cursor Up(Buffer buffer)
        {
            return new Cursor(Row - 1, Col).Clamp(buffer);
        }

        internal Cursor Down(Buffer buffer)
        {
            return new Cursor(Row + 1, Col).Clamp(buffer);
        }


        internal Cursor Left(Buffer buffer)
        {
            return new Cursor(Row, Col - 1).Clamp(buffer);
        }

        internal Cursor Right(Buffer buffer)
        {
            return new Cursor(Row, Col + 1).Clamp(buffer);
        }

        private Cursor Clamp(Buffer buffer)
        {
            Row = Math.Min(buffer.LineCount() - 1 , Math.Max(Row, 0));
            Col = Math.Min(buffer.LineLength(Row), Math.Max(Col, 0));
            return new Cursor(Row, Col);
        }

        internal Cursor MoveToCol(int col)
        {
            return new Cursor(Row, 0);
        }
    }

    class ANSI
    {
        public static void ClearScreen()
        {
            Console.Clear();
        }

        public static void MoveCursor(int row, int col)
        {
            Console.CursorTop = row;
            Console.CursorLeft = col;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of simple errors:

**1)**
In `Buffer.SplitLine(...)` you replace the next line with the second part of the split instead of inserting it after the first part:

> ```
> linesDeepCopy[row] = newLines[0];    
> linesDeepCopy[row + 1] = newLines[1];
> ```

instead you should do something like this:

```
    linesDeepCopy[row] = newLines[0];
    linesDeepCopy.Insert(row + 1, newLines[1]);
```

---

**2)**
In `Cursor.MoveToCol(int col)` you don't use the argument col:

> ```
>   internal Cursor MoveToCol(int col)
>   {
>     return new Cursor(Row, 0);
>   }
> ```

I suppose it to be:

```
  internal Cursor MoveToCol(int col)
  {
    return new Cursor(Row, col);
  }
```

---

**3)**

In `Editor.HandleInput()` you should check if a character is a text char before you insert:

> ```
>         else if (IsTextChar(character))
>         {
>           SaveSnapshot();
>           _buffer = _buffer.Insert(character.KeyChar.ToString(), _cursor.Row, _cursor.Col);
>           _cursor = _cursor.Right(_buffer);
>         }
>
> ....
>
>       private bool IsTextChar(ConsoleKeyInfo character)
>       {
>         return !Char.IsControl(character.KeyChar);
>       }
> ```

**4)**

This construct

> `(ConsoleModifiers.Control & character.Modifiers) != 0`

is potentially wrong because the value of `ConsoleModifiers.Control` could actually be `0`. Therefore you should do like this:

```
(ConsoleModifiers.Control & character.Modifiers) == ConsoleModifiers.Control
```

---

**Other things**

Consider if this input check is suitable:

> ```
>     if ((ConsoleModifiers.Control & character.Modifiers) != 0 && character.Key == ConsoleKey.Q)
>     {
>       Environment.Exit(0);
>     }
> ```

Because of the flag-behavior of ConsoleModifiers.Control it will be true if any combination of Modifiers are pressed that involve `Control (+ Q)`. It would maybe be more useful to make it more distinct like:

```
if (character.Modifiers == ConsoleModifiers.Control && character.Key == ConsoleKey.Q)
        {
          Environment.Exit(0);
        }
```

In this way you'll save the other combinations with `Control + Q` to other tools.

---

Your handling of state is nice and clean and easily maintained in that you always create a new instance when ever Buffer or Cursor changes. But it requires `immutable` objects. Cursor is not `immutable`:

> ```
> class Cursor
> {
>   public int Row { get; set; }
>   public int Col { get; set; }
>
>   ....
> }
> ```

Anyone (?) could change these parameters on objects placed on the history stack.

At least you should restrict `Cursor.Row` and `Cursor.Col` to be private settable only.

```
class Cursor
{
  public int Row { get; private set; }
  public int Col { get; private set; }

  ....
}
```

---

Consider to make the `Buffer.`

> ```
>   public int LineCount()
>   {
>     return _lines.Count();
>   }
> ```

as a parameter instead:

```
public int LineCount => _lines.Length;
```